# Predicate that take a list and give me the last item of this list do not work as i expect

Tags: prolog

I cannot understand why this predicate do not work as i expect.I thought that tail of list would be a list with only one item which would be the last element of list.So when i run query last(X,[1,2,3]) the result would be X=3 but i take false.

last(Item,[_|[Item]]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your `last` does is to try and unify the second argument to a list with exactly two elements. So what is a list?

- This is the empty list: `[]`
- This is a non-empty list: `[_|Rest]`

Here, `Rest` must be a list. So it can be the empty list, or a non-empty list. Here are proper lists of length 1, 2, 3: `[1|[]]`, `[1|[2|[]]]`, `[1|[2|[3|[]]]]`. It is important to understand that:

```
?- [1] = [X|[]].
X = 1.

?- [1,2] = [X|[Y|[]]].
X = 1,
Y = 2.

?- [1|[2]] = [X|[Y|[]]].
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

You can look at [this answer on Programmers Stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275680/the-dream-of-declarative-programming/275826#275826) for different ways of defining `last/2` in Prolog.